# Como usar una variable en nombre de tabla?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando actualizar la base de datos pero en el nombre de la table es una variable, seguramente tengo la sintaxis mal.

**Con esta variable SI funciona:**

```
$table = 'translate_es';
```

**Con esta variable NO funciona:**

```
$table = 'translate_'.$lang;
```

**Codigo completo:**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$lang = lang($_GET['lang']);

$table = 'translate_'.$lang;

    $tr_title = $_POST['tr_title'];
    $tr_slogan = $_POST['tr_slogan'];
    $tr_signin = $_POST['tr_signin'];
    $tr_makeacall = $_POST['tr_makeacall'];

$statment = $connect->prepare(
    "UPDATE $table SET
    tr_title = :tr_title,
    tr_slogan = :tr_slogan,
    tr_signin = :tr_signin,
    tr_makeacall = :tr_makeacall
    ");

    $statment->execute(array(
        ':tr_title' => $tr_title,
        ':tr_slogan' => $tr_slogan,
        ':tr_signin' => $tr_signin,
        ':tr_makeacall' => $tr_makeacall
        ));

    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);


}
```

Comment: Seguro estás tomando mal el idioma (tal vez por el get). Php me parece tiene funciones para tomar el idioma del user-agent del navegador. En dado caso no encuentre el idioma podrías hacer que use uno por defecto para evitar el error.

Comment: @PAGANA el idioma lo estoy obteniendo de edit_translate.php?lang=es

Comment: Puedes hacer un `var_dump($table);` y decirnos qué devuelve? Y otra cosa. Esa query podría ser vulnerable a SQL injection a través de la variable `$_GET['lang']`.